# How do I get Windows to adapt overscan settings depending on which device is connected?

Tags: windows-8, display, amd-catalyst, media-center

I have two monitors on my desk and a TV mounted above my desk; I often like to plug my HDMI from the TV into my PC to enjoy watching TV via Plex and other sorts of things. However, I have a couple issues. My TV and monitor have different over scanning options which cause things to be chopped off. I have to manually adjust this setting in my ATI Control Panel every time and it's a bit of a pain.

Is there a way to automate this process? (Detect when a display has changed) to launch Plex and change the display settings?

Comment: you state "ATI Control Panel". This is the old ATI legacy version or Catalyst Control Center?

Comment: The Catalyst Control Center, specifically. I have to change "Scaling Options" under "My Digital Flat Panels". It's a nuisance doing this every time, especially on a TV monitor.

Comment: Hi. The question is not very clear. Can you give more details about what specifically do you want to do? What do you consider "display change"? Is it when you connect something to an input/output? Or is it when you change the display settings? Also, I don't understand "different over scanning options".

Comment: @LuizAngelo Here's another way of rephrasing it: I'm looking for a way to action(s) when I switch my displays around. Specifically, looking to complete an action(s) when I disconnect my main monitor and plug in my HDTV.

Comment: What is the TV model? Does it have an option to auto adjust with options like Full pixel to screeen or P size?

Comment: @CarlB Not sure of the exact model... but it's a Sanyo LCD. I'll look into that; I think the issue is my monitor requires overscanning. My TV fits perfect with no over-scanning required.

Comment: Might be a good idea to add any info to your question about TV and monitor details.

Comment: Sanyo uses pix shape. is that available? Thought would be, set overscan for monitor and use pix shape for TV to adjust itself to the image.

Comment: @CarlB Just found my TV remote... Pix Shape did it! Thanks a lot! No need for some software now. I wish I could award you the bounty of 100 points that expired... :(

Comment: @VaughanHilts - I'll put that as an answer and you can accept;) that some rep anyway. Glad it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sanyo uses PixSshape as a way to auto adjust the screen image.

Set the overscan for monitor to your desired adjustment and use Pix Shape for TV to adjust itself to the image.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked for it and it seems to me there's not an utility out there to automate it. There's no tool to run when display settings are detected. If you're comfortable with the Windows API you can try do develop your own solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981520/detect-external-display-being-connected-or-removed-under-windows-7

The best I can offer you is http://12noon.com/?page_id=80. I've never used but it seems to do what you want.

It'll not run automatically, but at least it'll avoid setting it manually.

Comment: The APIs help but rolling my own is what I'd like to preferably avoid. :) Display changer can't do what I want check out over scanninghttp://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overscan#section_3 One of my monitors required to be over scanned while my TV does not.

Comment: I think you'll have to go with http://www.autohotkey.com/ then...